# RegEx: non-consecutive special characters only allowed in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am using following
`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/"`

The matching String should

- not start with a special character,
- not end with special character, and
- not include  consecutive symbols except . (dot) and _ (underscore).

But it is not working.
Please, any suggestion.

Comment: Likely get more help providing a working demo with enough test case strings to validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the word character class as a start (`[\w]` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

I'm not sure what you mean by consecutive symbols. But this might help:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]([\w.]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/
```

Maybe, have a look at the [JavaScript RegExp Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: Hi Carsten, consecutive symbols means in between string special characters are not allowed but  either  .  or _  allowed.

Comment: Inside a character class, `.` means `.`; it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @DattaDesai I changed the proposed RegEx, would you think that fits the description now?